# Color Coding a Table Based on the Count of a Column in the Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So I have a table. What it does is it has a count for different users. I want to color code it so that a certain color shows up based on the count for the users. So if the count is 0 it will be green. If the count is 1-2 it will be yellow. If the count is 3+ it will be red. I would like a query that can do this. The current search query for the table is "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE firstname ='$name'"

````
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    ID  |  firstname  |  lastname     |    address               |  count |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     1  |    john     |    doe        |james street, idaho, usa  |    2   |                    
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     2  |    cindy    |   smith       |rollingwood av,lyn, canada|     0  |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     3  |    rita     |   chatsworth  |arajo ct, alameda, cali   |    1   |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     4  |    randy    |   plies       |smith spring, lima, (peru)|    2   |                       
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     5  |    Matt     |   gwalio      |park lane, (atlanta), usa |    4   |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+```
Here is the table with the
````

Comment: Queries don't change colors.  Do you just want another column?  If so, use a `case` expression.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted another column that displayed a color based on the count. How would I use a case expression?

Comment: ```SELECT *, CASE `count` WHEN 0 THEN 'green' WHEN 1 THEN 'yellow' WHEN 2 THEN 'yellow' ELSE 'red' END AS color FROM ..```. But I recommend to create additional coloring table (from-till-color) and join it.

Comment: Alright, thank you.